# Why don't they drink wine on the West Wing?

Tags: the-west-wing

Of all the alcoholic beverages we see consumed on the show - from CJ and Josh cracking a beer, to Toby [going out for a Scotch](http://westwing.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Irish_Writers), cracking champagne to celebrate, or the President drinking vodka with his wife - we never see them drinking a [Chardonnay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chardonnay), and the [Cabernet Savignon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabernet_Sauvignon) never makes an appearance.

[image]

In other parts of the world, Australia and Europe, these [are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_belts_of_Europe#Wine_belt) [staple](http://theconversation.com/the-rise-of-australia-as-a-wine-nation-14875) [beverages](https://jakubmarian.com/wine-consumption-in-europe-by-country-per-year-per-capita/).

Was this a deliberate choice not to seem too upper crust?

My question is: **Why don't they drink wine on the West Wing?**

Answer (score 8):

### They Do

There are several occasions when wine is seen being imbibed or it is referred to. You just have to look for it.

[image]

[image]

This scene has champagne as well as other beverages being consumed.

Answer (score -1):

Also, when it comes to wine for the most part, wine requires more care than beer and whiskey.  Beer just needs a fridge, whiskey can sit on top of a table, and wine normally needs to be chilled, decantered, etc. so the 'upper crust' just wouldn't have had it as easily accessible in the White House.